Refresh (Resync with DB) a row of a ADOQuery (exactly a resultset) in Delphi / VB
Instead of refreshing a whole query that lasts too much, I need to refresh only current row of a result set of a ADOQuery.
After deep researches I found the following solutions:

If the query does not use join, we can use the following commands to refresh the current row:
ADOQuery1.UpdateCursorPos;
ADOQuery1.Recordset.Resync(adAffectCurrent, adResyncAllValues);
ADOQuery1.Resync([]);


If the query uses join but base tables are not the same, we can use the following commands:
ADOQuery1.Properties['Unique Catalog'].Value := <Main table database name >;
// Main table means a table that it's primary key is appeared in the SQL
ADOQuery1.Properties['Unique Table'].Value := <Main table name>;
ADOQuery1.Properties['Resync Command'].Value := <A parametric SQL Command >
ADOQuery1.UpdateCursorPos;
ADOQuery1.Recordset.Resync(adAffectCurrent, adResyncAllValues);
ADOQuery1.Resync([]);

or we can use TBetterADODataSet to easier set "Unique Catalog", "Unique Table" and "Resync Command". These dynamic properties is replaced by 3 properties named Unique_Catalog, Unique_Table and Resync_Command.


But I can not find any way to overcome the problem when the query joins two identical tables. It seems ADO confuse in this case and I got the following error at Recordset.Resync:

Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB
status value, if available. No work was done

Using view as copy of second table does not help.
I included details below:
My DBMS is MS SQL Server.
I have a DB named Test that contains only one table named Table1.
The DDL is as following:
CREATE DATABASE [Test]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] (
    [xCode]int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [xName]varchar(50) NULL,
    [xParentCode]int NULL,
    [xActive]char(1) DEFAULT 'T' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([xCode]),
    CONSTRAINT [Table1_fk] FOREIGN KEY ([xParentCode])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Table1] ([xCode])
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Note that the table is self referenced. It's used to keep the parent relationship between employees.
I insert the following rows in the table:



xCode
xName
xParentCode
xActive




1
John
NULL
T


2
Tom
NULL
T


3
Kate
2
T



that means Tom is parent of Kate.
I used the following SQL codes:
Select command:
SELECT A.*, B.xName as vName
FROM Table1 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 B ON B.xCode = A.xParentCode

Update Command
Update Table1 Set xActive = (case when xActive = ''T'' then ''F'' else
''T'' end)
Where xCode = <A row code>

Sync_Command
Select * From
(SELECT A.*, B.xName as vName
FROM Table1 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 B ON B.xCode = A.xParentCode) DerivedTable
Where xCode = ?

When I don't set Unique table, I get the following error when use resync function:

Key value for this row was changed or deleted at the data store. The local row in now deleted

When I set Unique_Table to "Table1", everything is OK when current row is row 1 and 2 but in the case of row 3, a new error occur:

Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.


Q1: When I set Unique_Catalog to "Test" and Unique_Schema to "dbo" I get the followng error:

Unique table is nonexistent or not completely specified.

What's wrong?
Q2: Is it possible to find a classic solution for this case?
I tried the following:

Create a view named View1 as a window over Table1 data and use the
following SQL:
Select command:
SELECT A.*, B.xName as vName
FROM Table1 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN View1 B ON B.xCode = A.xParentCode

Sync_Command
Select * From
(SELECT A.*, B.xName as vName
FROM Table1 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN View1 B ON B.xCode = A.xParentCode) DerivedTable
Where xCode = ?

But I get the same error.

I reconstructed SQLs without changes as follows:
Select command:
SELECT A.*, (Select xName
From Table1 B
Where B.xCode = A.xCode) as vName
FROM Table1 A

Sync_Command
SELECT A.*, (Select xName as vName
From Table1 B
Where B.xCode = A.xCode) as vName
FROM Table1 A
Where xCode = ?



In this case everything is OK for this query.
But I'm looking for a general solution that support all queries.
I implement it by Delphi and VB.Net but the result was identical. So I concluded that it is related to ADO or Database.
// Delphi Code
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls,
Forms,
Dialogs, Grids, DBGrids, DB, ADODB, StdCtrls, ShDBGrid,
BetterADODataSet,
DBClient;

type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
btnUpdate: TButton;
ADOQuery2: TADOQuery;
DBGrid1: TShDBGrid;
DataSource1: TDataSource;
ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
ADOQuery1xCode: TAutoIncField;
ADOQuery1xName: TWideStringField;
ADOQuery1vName: TWideStringField;
ADOQuery1xActive: TStringField;
btnRefreshCurrentRow: TButton;
procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
procedure ADOQuery1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
procedure btnRefreshCurrentRowClick(Sender: TObject);
procedure btnUpdateClick(Sender: TObject);
private
{ Private declarations }
public
{ Public declarations }
end;

var
Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses ADOInt;

{$R *.dfm}

{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
with ADOQuery1 do
begin
Close;
SQL.Text := ' SELECT A.*, B.xName as vName'+
' FROM Table1 A'+
' LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 B ON B.xCode = A.xOldCode';

Open;
end;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TForm1.ADOQuery1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
// ADOQuery1.Recordset.Properties['Update Resync'].Value :=
// adResyncAutoIncrement + adResyncUpdates + adResyncInserts;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TForm1.btnRefreshCurrentRowClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
ADOQuery1.Properties['Unique Catalog'].Value := 'Test';
ADOQuery1.Properties['Unique Table'].Value := 'Table1';
ADOQuery1.Properties['Resync Command'].Value :=
'Select * From ' +
' (SELECT A.*, B.xName as vName ' +
' FROM Table1 A ' +
' LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 B ON B.xCode = A.xOldCode) DerivedTable
' +
'Where xCode = ?';
ADOQuery1.UpdateCursorPos;
ADOQuery1.Recordset.Resync(adAffectCurrent, adResyncAllValues);
ADOQuery1.Resync([]);
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TForm1.btnUpdateClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
ADOConnection1.BeginTrans;

with ADOQuery2 do
begin
Close;
SQL.Text := ' Update Table1 Set xActive = (case when xActive =
''T'' then ''F'' else ''T'' end)'+
' Where xCode = ' +
ADOQuery1.FieldByName('xCode').AsString;
ExecSQL;
end;

ADOConnection1.CommitTrans;

btnRefreshCurrentRowClick(nil);
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

end.

// VB.Net
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports ADODB

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim cn As New Connection
    Dim rs As New Recordset
    
    Dim S As String
    Dim t As Integer
    
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.
    1;Password=<Pass>;Persist Security Info=True;" & _
    "User ID=<ID>;Initial Catalog=Test; Data
    Source=<Host name>"
    cn.Open()
    
    S = " SELECT A.*, B.xName as vName " & _
    " FROM Table1 A " & _
    " LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 B ON B.xCode = A.xParentCode"
    
    rs.ActiveConnection = cn
    rs.CursorLocation = CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
    rs.LockType = LockTypeEnum.adLockBatchOptimistic
    rs.Supports(CursorOptionEnum.adUpdateBatch)
    rs.CursorType = CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic
    rs.Open(S, cn, , , CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText)
    
    rs.MoveLast()
    t = rs.Fields("xCode").Value
    rem MsgBox(rs.Fields("xActive").Value)
    
    rs.Properties("Unique Table").Value = "Table1"
    rs.Properties("Resync Command").Value = _
    " Select * From " & _
    " (SELECT A.*, B.xName as vName" & _
    " FROM Table1 A" & _
    " LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 B ON B.xCode = A.xParentCode)
    DerivedTable" & _
    " Where xCode = ? "
    
    S = " Update Table1 " & _
    " Set xActive = (case when xActive = 'T' then 'F' else 'T'
    end)" & _
    " Where xCode = " & t
    cn.Execute(S, )
    
    rs.Resync(AffectEnum.adAffectCurrent,
    ResyncEnum.adResyncAllValues)
    rs.MoveLast()
    rem MsgBox(rs.Fields("xActive").Value)
End Sub

Can any one help me?
Any Idea?
